# Authenticating WiFi users with NFC tap points

Tags: ieee-802.11, authentication

I have been looking for a solution to a social WiFi issue at my company. We have poor WiFi authentication for customers in stores, but most of the issues stem from captive portal authentication. My goal is to use NFC tap points to connect users quickly and easily to our social WiFi SSID.

I have two options, either

A) I make a device myself,

OR

B) I find a company who already has a business making small NFC authentication devices.

I can't find any businesses making these devices. I found [a blog that shows how to make a simple version of this to connect your guests to home WiFi](https://www.digitaltrends.com/how-to/diy-nfc-coasters/), but home WiFi does not (usually) use captive portal.

I need something that can integrate with captive portal and the existing infrastructure, while also requiring few human resources to manage hundreds or thousands of these tap points.

I am not sure if this question is on topic here, but this seems like a network engineer question and its on the enterprise level (I'm working for a big company that needs this solution). Any leads to further information would be appreciated and (for context) I'm in South Africa.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. Captive portals are really above OSI layer-4. Businesses often use 802.1X for authentication, and it can automatically place guests into a guest network.

Answer (score 2):

As a slightly-alternative answer to your question, have you considered using QR codes for this?  It might be there are more QR-reading phones than NFC-reading phones.

I've had good success with QR-code posters for Wifi: it's easy to make posters with whatever instructions you like, plus you can print an expiry date.  With NFC you'll have to visit all the NFC devices and update them when your code changes, and when you miss one it generates a lot of aggravation.

Many ways to generate the QR code, including https://qifi.org/ which made the following:

[image]

Comment: I have considered QR codes, but paperless is the most sustainable practice. I would rather invest money into a device that can extend its functionality in case the future comes too soon.This is why I'm first looking into a service that can be provided from another company and be less clunky on the operational side.